# Typescript store updating one click late in a click event listener

Tags: javascript, typescript, listener, svelte

I'm trying to know if the shift key is being pressed when clicking a checkbox (I'm using Svelte). I need a store that will be updated in "real time" according to the state of the shift key.

I have a property in a `store.ts` file:

```
export let is_shift_pressed = writable(false)
```

In the `<script>` tag of my Svelte component:

```
import { is_shift_pressed } from './stores/store';

window.addEventListener('click', async function (e) {
   // e.shiftKey has always the correct value that I expect
   is_shift_pressed.set(e.shiftKey);
   // but the store is late of 1 click
});
```

I have a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" on:click={checkboxClicked}/>
```

When the checkbox is clicked, I try to display the value of the store. It should be equal to the value of `e.shiftKey` at the moment when the store was updated.

```
function checkboxClicked(){
   console.log(shiftPressed)
   // prints the value of the previous click
}
```

Comment: You do know that set of a writeable is async?

Comment: @Dimitar: That is not true. Any UI update that follows usually is, but the set and the subscribed handlers execute immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look for the shift key on the `event` that is passed to your click handler:

```js
function checkboxClicked(evt){
     console.log("Clicked", evt.shiftKey);
}
```